# Visio Set X and Y Coordinates

Tags: vba, visio

In Visio I am trying to change the shape's x and y coordinates. I am using the following code

```
VisioApp.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.Item(uniqueId).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).FormulaForceU = "18 in"
VisioApp.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.Item(uniqueId).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinY).FormulaForceU = "-13.77 in"
```

but after running the code the shape's coordinate becomes (14.25, -34.27). The code changes the coordinates but doesnt give the intended result. Any idea on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

On my side your code works ! Try define shape variable

> Dim sh As Shape
>   Set sh = VisioApp.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.Item(UniqueID)
>   sh.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).FormulaForceU = "18 in"
>   sh.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinY).FormulaForceU = "-13.77 in"

**UPDATE**
Please open page's shapeshet and check **Ruler & Grid** section
[image]
If **XRulerOrigin**/**YRulerOrigin** is not equal **0** then you can see incorrect coordinates for shapes in window **Size & Position**

[image]